# how to write an code for upload a file in .net using C# and SQL for windows application

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

after uploading the file in windows appliaction how can i access it

Answer (score -1):

ui :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
```

code behind :

```
  protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

}

you can follow below link for this

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Comment: OP has mentioned windows application and not the web.